# MySQL getting a record closest to one year old

Tags: mysql, datetime, math

I'm playing around with my forum (It's home grown, not phpbb, or any other 3rd party forum), and I'd like to have a way to say, "One year ago, you posted this: XXXX".

The problem is, I'm not sure how to query for whatever comes closest to one year old. I feel like I'd need to build a calculation into the query, something like

PSUEDO coded something like this..

`SELECT *, ABS(DATE(timestamp-now)) as diff FROM table ORDER BY diff LIMIT 1` - where DIFF would be the math of how close I can get this to one year ago.

Any suggestions on how to structure this would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ABS((curdate() - interval 1 year) - date_column) as diff 
FROM table 
ORDER BY diff 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I ended up pulling the number of seconds in a year before I saw this and got it working, but that's the solution I took. As long as there's a record in the table, it'll return something, and it'll always be the closest to one year old then I can get. Thanks!!